# Is this a valid jQuery plugin pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins, plugins

```
(function( $ ){  
    MY_SINGLETON_OBJ = MY_SINGLETON_OBJ || (function () { // initialize the singleton using an immediate anonymous function which returns an object
        // init here (only happens once even if this plugin is included multiple times)
        console.log("Initialized");
        return {
            version: "0.1"
            // return values that are to be accessible from the singleton
        };
    })();
    $.fn.MyJqueryObjectMethod = function (a, b, c) {
        // perform tasks
        return this; // maintain chainability
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The singleton is polluting the global namespace. Is there a better way to define it?

Comment: So you want us to debug for you?

Comment: This would probably be better suited to [CodeReview.SE]. But anyway, if this is the whole plugin (I mean, there's nothing outside of the outer function) then `MY_SINGLETON_OBJ` will cause an error because it hasn't been defined.

Comment: Edited to make the question more specific.

Comment: @minitech Wouldn't it get assigned the object returned from the anon function?

Comment: @StevenLu: You have a `MY_SINGLETON_OBJ ||` before it gets assigned, and that's the major error, but it's bad practice anyway. Change both to `window.MY_SINGLETON_OBJ` and everything will work fine.

Comment: @minitech okay. Is there a better place to put it than `window`?

Comment: @StevenLu: Not really, you want it to be global. You could put it on `jQuery` instead, but... not much point in doing so.

Comment: Avoiding global namespace pollution doesn't mean "don't ever declare anything global," it just means take care and be selective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks to me like it would work, though I think you should at least declare your singleton globally rather than use an implicit definition.

You don't have to be that tricky.  You can just as easily do this which I think it a bit more readable and obvious:

```
// explicit global definition
var MY_SINGLETON_OBJ;

(function( $ ){  
    if (!MY_SINGLETON_OBJ) {
        // initalize the singleton here
        MY_SINGLETON_OBJ = {};
        MY_SINGLETON_OBJ.prop1 = 1;
    }
    $.fn.MyJqueryObjectMethod = function (a, b, c) {
        // perform tasks
        return this; // maintain chainability
    };
})(jQuery);
```